# Loops running into each other

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, jquery, javascript

I have 3 loops on one page, each pulling a different CPT into a portfolio like layout.

Live: http://iassc.baltimoredrew.com/providers/

Gist: https://gist.github.com/3503334

However the tags for the second and third sections are inheriting the ones from the loop before it.

Also when I click on one of the tags to filter it, it filters all 3 loops. JS issue? In fact, could it all be JS related?

I know there are probably better ways to do this instead of multiple Custom Post Types & Loops. But it's kinda in there now. I'm hesitant to start all over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple fix, from what I can tell.. after each "loop" you need to reset your term list..

```
$term_list = '';
```